# windows 10 transfer of files from old computer to new computer

Tags: windows, windows-easy-transfer

I backed up my old computer which was Windows 7 with Easy Transfer.  The files have a MIG extension.  I tried to load them into my new computer which uses Windows 10 without any success.

I did save my data/pictures/video, etc. and was able to transfer them.

How do I get my favorites/pfd programs, etc. to transfer over?

Answer (score 5):

There is no Windows Easy Transfer in Windows 10 (phased out in Windows 8.1), so you have to copy/reconfigure what you want manually, or find a 3rd party alternative.

Microsoft has teamed up with [Laplink](http://www.laplink.com) to provide a free copy of PC Mover Express [until the end of Aug. 2016](http://betanews.com/2015/09/01/microsoft-makes-it-easy-to-switch-to-windows-10-with-free-pcmover-express/):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/transfer-your-data

Here's another one as an example:

http://www.zinstall.com/products/zinstall-easy-transfer

> Got a new computer and need to transfer all your stuff from the old one? Upgrading your computer to Windows 10 or to Windows 8? No matter the scenario, Zinstall Easy Transfer will do the job!

**Note:** I've never tried this product personally, and it may just be a virus-injector for all I know. It's only offered here to show that such a thing exists. :)

Comment: A slightly safer option is Laplink's free software.  Microsoft has partnered with Laplink to offer this functionality to Windows 10.  [Here](http://betanews.com/2015/09/01/microsoft-makes-it-easy-to-switch-to-windows-10-with-free-pcmover-express/), It talks about the offer [Here](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/09/01/microsoft-provides-free-copy-of-pcmover-express-to-aid-file-transfers) with the official download link **[here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/transfer-your-data)**

Comment: @Ramhound I was actually going to include that, but couldn't find any valid/current links.  :)  So, nice, I'll add what you've suggested.

Comment: Would be great to know if Laplink actually CAN read the Windows easy Transfer MIG files, as this is not mentionned anywhere.

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris There is no intention here to suggest that Laplink can read MIG files, that's why it's not mentioned. :)  You would use Laplink *instead* of WET.

Comment: Although the OP's question wasn't clear, the assumption is that the original data has been backup-ed to a MIG file, the original disk has been formatted, a new Win10 OS has been installed, and the backup files are stuck in a MIG file we cannot even restore. I ended up using [MigRestore](https://www.visser.com.au/blog/migrecover-for-microsofts-windows-easy-transfer/)